# Page scrolling even when there's no content

Tags: html, css

My web page is scrolling to the right even though there's no content there and there's just empty white space there. The content isn't over 100vw and if I reduce it, then it doesn't fill the page.

Perhaps some of the CSS I've written has caused this? What do I need to change/add to my code to fix this? Thanks.
Home.css

```
    #wrapper {padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
    .section 
     {
      padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
      width: 100vw;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      text-align: justify;
      top: -110px;
      left: -230px;
      height: 100vh;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
      background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    h1  {
    color: white;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    }

    .section:after {
      content: '';
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      background: rgba(214, 87, 214, 0.03);
    }
    .name {
      font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
        font-size: 62px;
        margin-top: 90px;
      animation-name: slideInLeft;
      animation-duration: 4s;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    @keyframes slideInLeft {
      0% {margin-left: -1600px;}
      100% {margin-left: 0px;}
    }

    .role {
      animation-name: slideInRight;
      animation-duration: 4s;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    @keyframes slideInRight {
      0% {margin-right: -1600px;}
      100% {margin-right: 0px;}
    }
    /* width */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 20px;
    }

    /* Track */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background: #ffffff;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background: rgb(155, 12, 48)  ;
      background: radial-gradient(circle, rgb(155, 12, 48) 0%, rgb(63, 2, 87) 100%);
      border-radius: 0.6em;
      height: 22px;
    }

    .name {
      color: rgb(231, 139, 139);
    }
```

App.css

```
    :root {
      --off-white: #fafafa;
    }
    .nav {
      background-color: var(--off-white);
      position: sticky;
      top: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 80px;
      z-index: 1000;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }

    .nav-btn {
      height: 60px;
      width: 60px;
    }

    .nav .nav-content {
      max-width: 900px;
      padding: 0rem 3rem;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .nav-item {
      display: inline;
      top: 40px;
      margin-left: 2rem;
      color: white;
      font-size: 18px;
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative;
    }

    .nav-item:hover {
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .section-content {
      max-width: 800px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 40px;
    }
```

Comment: Would it be possible to see the HTML as well? Or the link to the web page? It's really hard to tell from CSS alone.

Comment: Use ```*{padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}``` instead of  ```#wrapper {padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the overflow property,

{
overflow:hidden
}

Answer (score 0):

it's kinda hard to analyze it without HTML code.
But maybe that line is your problem:

```
.section 
 {
  ..
  left: -230px; 
  ..
}
```